Piechart angle selection on tapping a sector instead of touch and hold gesture using SwiftUI Chart framework
I have created piechart using swiftUI Chart framework. Also made the chart interactive by using chartAngleSelection modifier. But, this will work only when we touch and hold the sector of Pie chart. As per my requirement, an overlay should be dispalyed with the sector detail on a single tap of Sectors.
Here is the code with touch and hold selection
                            Chart{
                            ForEach(pieChartData.indices, id: \.self){ index in
                                
                                SectorMark(angle: .value(Text(pieChartData[index].label ?? ""), pieChartData[index].value ?? 0.0),
                                           innerRadius:((pieChartData[index].label == selectedItem?.label) ? .ratio(0.5) : .ratio(0.6)),
                                           outerRadius:((pieChartData[index].label == selectedItem?.label) ? .ratio(1.0) : .ratio(0.9)),
                                           angularInset: 1.0)
                                
                                .foregroundStyle(by:.value("Key",pieChartData[index].label ?? ""))
                                
                            }
                        }
                        .chartForegroundStyleScale(domain: pieChartData.map({$0.label ?? ""}), range: pieChartData.map({$0.color ?? Color.random()}))
                        .chartAngleSelection(value: $selectedAngle)
                        .chartLegend(alignment:.leading, spacing: 8)
                        .chartBackground { chartProxy in
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                if let anchor = chartProxy.plotFrame {
                                    let frame = geometry[anchor]
                                    titleView
                                        .position(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
                                        .padding(3)
                                }
                            }
                        }

I have tried with the ChartGesture modifier and SpatialGesture as suggested in https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/738467. I could show the overlay on tapping the sector, but could not dismiss the overlay when tapping outside the Chart even if the SelectedAngle is set to 0 by adding a tap gesture to the Parent View.
Please find the below code in which I tried to implement the tap gesture
Chart{
                                    ForEach(pieChartData.indices, id: \.self){ index in
                                        SectorMark(angle: .value(Text(pieChartData[index].label ?? ""), pieChartData[index].value ?? 0.0),
                                                   innerRadius:((pieChartData[index].label == selectedItem?.label) ? .ratio(0.5) : .ratio(0.6)),
                                                   outerRadius:((pieChartData[index].label == selectedItem?.label) ? .ratio(1.0) : .ratio(0.9)),
                                                   angularInset: 0.4)
                                        
                                        
                                        .foregroundStyle(by:.value("Key", pieChartData[index].label ?? ""))
                                        
                                    }
                            }
                            .chartForegroundStyleScale(range: pieChartLegendsColors)
                            .chartAngleSelection(value: $selectedAngle)
                            .chartLegend(alignment:.center, spacing: 16)
                            .chartGesture({ chart in
                                SpatialTapGesture()
                                    .onEnded { event in
                                        let angle = chart.angle(at: event.location)
                                        chart.selectAngleValue(at: angle)
                                    }
                            })
                    
                            .frame(height: 300)
                            .overlay {
                                if selectedItem != nil{
                                    titleView
                                        .padding(3)
                                        .background {
                                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 3)
                                                .foregroundStyle(.black.opacity(0.6))
                                        }
                                }
                            }

Is there any other solution to achieve this?
